# Locate variables in scope?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, local, detect

Is there a way to locate all variables inside a scope? e.g.

```
var localScope = function() {
    var var1 = "something";
    var var2 = "else...";

   console.log(LOCAL_SCOPE);
};
```

where `LOCAL_SCOPE` so returns an object like:

```
{
    var1: "something",
    var2: "else..."
}
```

I know a can do this by making a local object. but i seek a way to locate all variables without having any idea of them existing.

Comment: is this a question resulting from an issue you are having? If so, please also put in that question

Comment: This isn't possible. What do you need this for?

Comment: Questions don't go in answers.

Comment: This is the best answer that's possible unless he adds context to the question.

Comment: The first sentence, perhaps; it would be borderline due to its short size. But combine that with your question and it becomes a conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reliable way to obtain *all* local variables. The closest you can get is by obtaining the source of the function.

If you don't know a reference to the current function (eg name), you have to use the deprecated (and forbidden in ECMAScript 5) `argument.callee`.

When you've got a reference to the function, you have to obtain the string of the source, either by the non-standard `toSource()` method, or `.toString()`.

After the string is obtained, you have to get all variable names, eg, by using a RegExp. Combining this method with looping through `window`, you can get all local variables of functions which are defined in the global scopes. Then, `eval` (!!!) has to be used to get a reference to the local variables.

---

In short, you should not attempt to look for a method which locates all local variables, because there's no reliable way to achieve this.